# Changing the Vector elements from one class to another

Tags: java, vector

I have a `ClassA` and a `ClassB` implemented like this:

```
Class ClassB {
   //[...]
}

Class ClassA {
   //[...]

   public ClassB toClassB() {
       //[...]

       return new ClassB("Some data");
   }
}
```

Also, I have a vector whose elements are `ClassA` objects:

```
Vector vector;

vector.add(new ClassA("AAA"));
vector.add(new ClassA("BBB"));
vector.add(new ClassA("CCC"));
```

This code changes the vector elements from `ClassA` to `ClassB`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
    vector.set(i, ((ClassA) vector.get(i)).toClassB());
}
```

Is there a simpler/efficient way to do the same?

**EDIT :** I changed the vector type from `Vector<ClassA>` to only `Vector`, as it's in the original code.

Comment: Your code won't compile.  You are trying to set a ClassB object into the vector declared as Vector<ClassA> and ClassB does not extend ClassA

Comment: @AleksG You're right. Thank you. I fixed the code as it is working now in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Vector<ClassB> convert(Vector<ClassA> v){

    Vector<ClassB> result = new Vector(v.size());

    for(ClassA a : vector){
        result.add(a.toClassB());
    }
    //optional: v.clear()
    return result;
}
```

This static method could be in any class (probably it should be in `ClassA`, due to cohesion). Still, from a oop perspective, the class relationship seems odd. If there is no meaningful difference between `ClassA` and `ClassB`, you should either investigate, if you need both classes, or if there is a useful abstraction for them (regarding separation of concerns).

Comment: I'm developing a Java code to access Lotus Notes data and `ClassA` is `lotus.domino.DateTime` and `ClassB` is `java.util.Date`. As you can see, they have the same data but in different ways as they come from different libraries. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you can do something like:

```
    final List<ClassA> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<ClassB> listB = listA.stream().map(x -> x.toClassB()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```